# In Google Sheets how do I replicate a range of formulas horizontally?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 4 cells with 4 different formulas adjacent to each other horizontally.

If I want to repeat these 4 cells horizontally I need to select and drag them all the way to the end of the sheet every time, and if I add more columns I need to do that again.

Now with just 4 cells it's pretty simple, but I need to do the same with a 4x6 range of cells and I may have to expand this range in the future.

Isn't there a faster solution or a keyboard shortcut to do it?

Edit: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vPTVj_iK6jbt37-iWunH3Zc-9CD8M4QXaoebNA3P9wQ/edit?usp=sharing This is an editable Sheet with the formulas

Comment: You should attach the link google sheet containing the formula you want to repeat for better support

Comment: which formulas do you use, sometimes it is possible to build in one formula for all the columns with arrayformula

Comment: I agree with Theza and Mike Steelson: it's not really possible to advise you on how to address a formula issue when we can't see the existing formulas, data, data types, setup, etc. Please consider sharing a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), being specific about which formulas should repeat and what those formulas currently do.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vPTVj_iK6jbt37-iWunH3Zc-9CD8M4QXaoebNA3P9wQ/edit?usp=sharing Here's an example Sheet with the formulas

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question within the scope of SO!